# How to animate a mesh to slide without freezing/ jumping?

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I have two meshes on my canvas `mesh` and `mesh2`. I loaded `mesh2.position.x` set to `10` so that it is on the right side of the web page. I have a left arrow button on my page, and would like `mesh2` to slide to its position to `0` when that arrow is clicked, so as to bring it to the center of the web page.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("arrow left")[0].addEventListener("click", slideAnimation, false);

   function slideAnimation() {

    var pos = mesh2.position.x;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
      if (pos <= 0) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        pos -= .8;
        mesh2.position.x = pos;
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is that when I try to animate this function, it seems to jump/skip a few pixels on the way over to the center of the page. I have tried setting a fixed width on the canvas:

```
canvas {
    width: 2500px;
}
```

But the lagging is still there. Does anyone know of a solution to slide the mesh smoothly across the canvas? I'm aiming to do something like the homepage of this website: https://www.getwearable.net/fitness

Comment: Try with `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: Right, thanks that’s much better. If you leave an answer I’ll accept.

Comment: I'm not implying that this technique is not new to you--everyone encounters things for the first time asynchronously--but using `requestAnimationFrame` for smooth animation (and its benefits over `setInterval`) is fairly well-discussed already, both on SO and across the web.The `three.js` examples also make heavy use of `requestAnimationFrame`. IMO, I don't believe a full answer is truly necessary, unless we can find one that answers the generalized question of smooth animation, allowing us to mark this question as a duplicate.